# Calling a function after time period has elapsed since last key press in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, keypress, tkinter-entry

I have an entry in tkinter application in Python. If user changes the entry content, program reacts via `onValidate` function.

Now I would like to select all text in the entry field, if user has not pressed any keys for a while.

Below I have tried to `select_all_text` after `1000` ms using `after` function, but it seems not to work.

```
import tkinter as tk  

class MyEntry(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.vcmd = (self.register(self.onValidate),
                        '%d', '%i', '%P', '%s', '%S', '%v', '%V', '%W')

        self.entry = tk.Entry(self, validate="key", validatecommand=self.vcmd)
        self.entry.pack(side="top", fill="x")

        self.select_all_text()

    def select_all_text(self):
        self.entry.focus()
        self.entry.select_range(0,'end')

    def onValidate(self, d, i, P, s, S, v, V, W):
        self.root.after(1000, self.select_all_text)

        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MyEntry(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    root.mainloop()
```

Also the timer should reset each time a new key is pressed, so that `select_all_text` is called only after a long enough time has elapsed since last key press. In the example below `select_all_text` is called after each key press, which is not desired behavior.

I was thinking that could one track the time since last key press, and if it exceeds a certain threshold, then function would be called. That kind of method would also solve the problem.

How to call a function if a long enough time has elapsed since last key press in tkinter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you keep a reference to the id that `after` returns, you can cancel it with `after_cancel`. With this, you can cancel the scheduled function and reschedule it on every keypress:

```
class MyEntry(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.after_id = None

        ...

    def onValidate(self, d, i, P, s, S, v, V, W):
        if self.after_id:
            self.parent.after_cancel(self.after_id)
        self.after_id = self.parent.after(1000, self.select_all_text)

        return True
```

Note that I also saved the root window that you pass as the argument to `MyEntry` in `self.parent` and used that to call `after` on.

---

P.S. You don't really need the Entry's `validatecommand` command to do this (but you could if you already use the `validatecommand` anyway of course). You can bind the function to every keypress:

```
class MyEntry(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.after_id = None

        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.bind('<Key>', self.entry_keypress)

        ...

    def entry_keypress(self, e):
        print(self.after_id)
        if self.after_id:
            self.parent.after_cancel(self.after_id)
        self.after_id = self.parent.after(1000, self.select_all_text)
```